# NodeJs Buffer is not attached to Nodemailer file

Tags: node.js, azure, nodemailer, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

Currently on my project I am dealing with a situation and I feel it is a problem of syntax but I am not getting the right answer and kinda feeling stressed and tilt over it for the last three days.

I am using three libraries NodeJs, Html-pdf(phantomJS) and Nodemailer.

this is the block of code in question (everything is inside a major async function that is a resolver of graphQl)

```
 await pdf.create(html, options).toBuffer(async (err, buffer) => {
          //i = new ;
          //console.log(typeof(buffer))
          await buffer;
          await transporter.sendMail({
            from: '"Example" example@example.com', // sender address
            to: `${a1.dataValues.email}`, // list of receivers
            subject: `${text2}`, // Subject line
            text: `${text}`, // plain text body
            html: `<p> ${text} </p>`, // html body
            attachments: [
              {
                filename: `${a1.dataValues.kitID}.pdf`,
                content: buffer,
                contentType: "application/pdf",
              },
            ],
          });
        });
```

The email is sent but I get this in the browser

[image: result]

The attachment is sent but I guess it is "undefined" and I have been struggling with finding a way to fix this. Can someone please help me?

I tried as well to do

```
 attachments: [
              {
                filename: `${a1.dataValues.kitID}.pdf`,
                content: new buffer.from(buffer),
                contentType: "application/pdf",
              },
            ],
```

```
 attachments: [
              {
                filename: `${a1.dataValues.kitID}.pdf`,
                content: new buffer(buffer),
                contentType: "application/pdf",
              },
            ],
```

```
 attachments: [
              {
                filename: `${a1.dataValues.kitID}.pdf`,
                content: new buffer.from(buffer,'base64'),
                contentType: "application/pdf",
              },
            ],
```

but all of those crash the app in Azure. The all thing works perfectly locally, but not when deployed.

Comment: when crashes the server what is the log of the server?

Comment: What do you mean `undefined`?

Comment: @OblicionA the log says the server is "unhealthy"

Comment: @JimXu it basically does not open the pdf file that is sent

Comment: Is that you cannot open it?

Comment: @JimXu Hi again. the problem is way bigger it is related to Azure not allowing puppeteer or phantomJs on the app service

Comment: @thelittlemaster Azure app service does not support User32/GDI32. So you need to some frameworks that do not leverage User32/GDI32 extensively, such as `wkhtmltopdf` ; https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions. Or you also can try to create your custom docker image then deploy to Azure.

Comment: @thelittlemaster Do you have any update?